# DTD validation before XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, dtd

I have to write an XSLT to convert a XML file into another XML file. The original input file has to valid with respect to a DTD. Is there a way in which XSLT can validate the input xml file against the DTD before converting it ? Also reject the input file if it does not conform to the DTD.

Also , I will run the XSLT in a tool like Oxygen XML Editor.

Thanks in advance.
JK

Comment: There is no reason to vote to close this for "off-topic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this through your XSLT processor. I don't think there is a way to do this in XSLT itself.

In oXygen, you can go to "XML / XSLT-FO-XQuery / XSLT / Saxon / Saxon-HE/PE/EE" in Preferences and turn DTD validation on or off (there is a combo box).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But I would have preferred something XSLT built-in functions :)

Answer (score 1):

Not with builtin XSLT-1.0 functions (which cannot detect non-well-formedness in a clean manner either). Your environment may be able to provide this through other tools such as DOM Builders.

Comment: @jkcool - See my answer about the settings in oXygen for Saxon (XSLT 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the tool you are using. In this case, this is a question about the Oxygen editor. There's nothing in the specification for XSLT that requires a processor to perform DTD validation when reading XML.

Comment: But if there was an XSD associated with the XML , then it would have possible to validate the input xml with it. Am I right ?

Comment: Only if the tool you are using chooses to implement and enable XSD validation. It's nothing to do with XSLT itself.

Comment: @jkcool the ONLY thing the XSLT processor has to do is check for well-formedness. Some of them may just crash horribly on non-well-formed input (i.e. not give any idea what is wrong)